# Generating wrong URL in the form action using form_for in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I am using rails 4.0.0. I am a newcomer to rails and learning rails watching video tutorials and stuck in a problem so need some help.

I have a controller called Subjects and following is the code

**Subject Constoller**

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_subject, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @subjects = Subject.all
  end

  def list
    @subjects = Subject.all
    #@subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
  end 

  def show
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subject = Subject.new(:name => "default")  
  end

  def create
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
        if @subject.save
        redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else
        render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @subject.update(subject_params)
        redirect_to @subject
    else
        render("edit")
    end
  end

  def delete
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy   
    Subject.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to(:action => "list")
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_subject
      @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def subject_params
      params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
    end

end
```

I created a view for the List Action

**View for the List Action**

```
<h1>List</h1>
<div class="subject list">
  <h2>Subjects</h2>

  <table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= subject.position %></td>
      <td><%= subject.name %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to 'Show', subject, :class => 'action show'%>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_subject_path(subject), :class => 'action edit' %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action delete' %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

I also have a view for delete and code is as follows

**View for Delete Action**

```
<h1>Delete</h1>
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subject delete">
  <h2>Delete Subject</h2>

  <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => "destroy", :id => @subject.id}) do |f|%>

    <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this subject?</p>

    <p class="reference-name"><%= @subject.name %></p>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Delete Subject") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Here is the configuration of my routes file**

```
SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do  
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'
  root 'demo#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  get 'demo/index'
  get 'demo/hello'
  get 'demo/other_hello'
  #get 'subjects/index'
  get 'subjects/list'
  get 'subjects/delete'
  get  '/subjects/:id/destroy' => 'subjects#destroy'
  resources :subjects
  get 'subjects/show'
  get 'subjects/new'
  get 'subjects/:id' => 'subjects#show'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products
  #resources :subjects

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

So the main concept is as follows when i will call **`http://localhost:3000/subjects/list`** it will show all the subjects and there is also three button that is **show**, **edit** and **delete** and after clicking on the delete link it will go to the **delete view** and after clicking on the submit button of the form it will be deleting the particular item.

But the main problem is that the **form_for** in **delete view** is producing the **url** in the **form action** is **/subjects/8** where **8** is the id of the subject to be deleted but the **url** should be **/subjects/destroy?id=8** to delete the item but when **id** is passed along with the **action** in **form_for** it produces the wrong url but when only the action is passed it produces the url as **/subjects/destroy**.

I cannot figure out what is wrong so please help. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: You really need to clean up your routes and your controller - you're duplicating all of the resourceful routes (badly - URLs that change state should *not* be GET routes) and you're duplicating your index action in your list action.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i don't understand the route concept clearly can you please help me to understand that clearly in depth.

Comment: I can point you to the very well written Rails routing guide - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a link with delete method instead use a form.

```
<p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this subject?</p>

<p class="reference-name"><%= @subject.name %></p>

<%= link_to 'Delete Subject', @subject, method: :delete %>
```

UPDATE

If you want to use a form for destroy action, try this :

```
<% form_for @subject, :html => {:method => :delete} do |form| %>
```

Comment: thanks buddy.....i think this will work but want to know why my code is not working......take care dear.....

Comment: You can use using form (I don't know how) [check this ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8192107/1297435), but that's not recommend because most browsers don't support methods other than "GET" and "POST" when it comes to submitting forms.

Comment: I'd reread that reference.  It discusses how to successfully use form_for delete.  Also, please post the output of rake routes.

Comment: Uploaded the routes file please have a look at the edited post.....thanks to all for helping.......

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for(@subject, :url => {:action => "destroy") do |f|%>
```

Instead of this:

```
<%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => "destroy", :id => @subject.id}) do |f|%>
```

You don't need to mention the id because in form_for it takes id of the variable mentioned by default.

Comment: I have tried it but its not working......when returning to the destroy action as the id is not set it gives error as **"Couldn't find Subject with id=destroy"**. Anyways thanks a lot dear for your help.

Comment: @Himadri mention "post 'subjects/destroy' "  in routes.rb because you are submitting the form.